# TagSpaces on Windows IIS WebDav

Tags: windows, webdav

Talking about self hosted TagSpaces here:
https://www.tagspaces.org/
https://docs.tagspaces.org/selfhosting.html

- We installed Webdav on IIS (Windows web server.)
- We created a site using the tagspaces website files.
- The path for the root folder is D:\shares\Design\TagSpaces
- When we enter it as a location the site says it fails to open it.
- Not sure if it’s because webdav is not working correctly or if it’s because we need to use a different syntax to the location (or both.)

Chrome inspector gives a 401 unauthorized after attempted connection.

Are there some instructions for setting it up on Windows server and what would be the syntax for the path to the root folder containing the files to be accessed?